# Taking Max of a column based on certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need your help to get the max of CAP_PRICE based on certain criteria in the select statement of sql:

```
IF sid_rnk =0 and prd_id_rnk =1 and cap_price <> 0 
   then Max(cap_price) group by (sid_rnk,prd_rnk) as CAP1

Else if sid_rnk =0 and prd_id_rnk =2 and cap_price <> 0  and cap1 = 0
   then Max(cap_price) group by (sid_rnk,prd_rnk) as cap2

Else if sid_rnk =0 and prd_id_rnk =3 and cap_price <> 0 and cap2 = 0
   then Max(cap_price) group by (sid_rnk,prd_rnk) as cap3

Else if sid_rnk =1 and prd_id_rnk =1 and cap_price <> 0 and cap3 = 0
   then Max(cap_price) group by (sid_rnk,prd_rnk) as cap4

Else if sid_rnk =1 and prd_id_rnk =2 and cap_price <> 0 and cap4 = 0
   then Max(cap_price) group by (sid_rnk,prd_rnk) as cap5

Else if sid_rnk =1 and prd_id_rnk =3 and cap_price <> 0 and cap5 = 0
   then Max(cap_price) group by (sid_rnk,prd_rnk)
```

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE sap_prod
(
prd_id_rnk int,
sld_to_rnk int,
CAP_geo_1 varchar(20),
F_I_geo_2 varchar(20),
CAP_price int
)


INSERT INTO sap_prod     
       ( prd_id_rnk, sld_to_rnk, CAP_geo_1, F_I_geo_2, CAP_price ) 
SELECT      1,0,'ASMO','ASMO',0   UNION ALL
SELECT      1,0,'ASMO','ASMO',0   UNION ALL 
SELECT      1,0,'ASMO','ASMO',0   UNION ALL 
SELECT      2,0,'WW'  ,'ASMO',0   UNION ALL 
SELECT      2,0,'WW'  ,'ASMO',0   UNION ALL 
SELECT      2,0,'WW'  ,'ASMO',0   UNION ALL 
SELECT      3,0,'EMEA','ASMO',0   UNION ALL 
SELECT      3,0,'EMEA','ASMO',0   UNION ALL 
SELECT      3,0,'IJKK','ASMO',0   UNION ALL 
SELECT      3,0,'IJKK','ASMO',0   UNION ALL
SELECT      1,1,'ASMO','ASMO',0   UNION ALL
SELECT      1,1,'ASMO','ASMO',0   UNION ALL 
SELECT      1,1,'ASMO','ASMO',0   UNION ALL 
SELECT      2,1,'WW'  ,'ASMO',0   UNION ALL 
SELECT      2,1,'WW'  ,'ASMO',0   UNION ALL 
SELECT      2,1,'WW'  ,'ASMO',0   UNION ALL 
SELECT      3,1,'EMEA','ASMO',35  UNION ALL 
SELECT      3,1,'EMEA','ASMO',40  UNION ALL 
SELECT      3,1,'IJKK','ASMO',70  UNION ALL 
SELECT      3,1,'IJKK','ASMO',50
```

The result should be : `70`

Comment: What is sid_rnk in your criteria?

Comment: And what is the difference with just taking the max value of `CAP_price`?

Comment: @Lamak : If any criteria satisfies above it should stop there.For example if 2nd row has CAP_PRICE as 5..it should give the result 5

Comment: @AndreyGurinov : This is an intermediate table where already some logic has been aplied and the data comes to us in this format.prd_id_rnk is the column for some logic.

Comment: Is `sid_rnk` the same as `sld_to_rnk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but I think you need this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 cap_price
FROM 
(
    SELECT sld_to_rnk, prd_id_rnk, Max(cap_price) AS cap_price 
    FROM sap_prod
    WHERE cap_price <> 0
    group by sld_to_rnk, prd_id_rnk 
) AS tmp
ORDER BY sld_to_rnk, prd_id_rnk
```

Comment: I think this might only break if negative prices were possible, which I doubt to be the case. At the very least, this is on the right track and, therefore, useful.